# Context.User lost after Redirect

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

I am trying to integrate OAuth into some ASP.NET legacy code.

For this I am using OWIN. I'm already able to open the External Provider login page, redirect back to my application and retrieve the account details, but I am having problems on how to keep the user authenticated in the subsequent http requests.

My initial flow is the following:

1. I open the `Login.aspx` page (from my web application);
2. I click a button to login using an External Provider;
3. In the External Provider login page, I introduce my credentials and click Confirm;
4. The credentials get validated and I get redirected to `LoginExternal.aspx` page (from my web application);

In `LoginExternal.aspx`, I have the following `Page_Load` logic:

```
    protected void Page_Load()
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            var loginInfo = Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfo();
            LogInOAuth(loginInfo.Email);
        }
    }
```

The `loginInfo` object is correclty filled and contains the data returned by the external provider, including the email address.

In the `LogInOAuth` method I do the following:

```
    private void LogInOAuth(string email)
    {
        var id = new BusUser().getIdByUserEmail(email);

        if (id > 0)
        {
            Session.Add("userID", id);

            Context.User = new CustomUserPrincipal(false, 0, new UserDetails()
            {
                ID = id.ToString(),
                Name = email
            });

            var data = UserDetails.EncondeUserData(new object[] { id.ToString(), email });

            CreateCookie(data, "MyAppName", DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60));

            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx", false);
        }
    }
```

After setting the `Context.User`, if I do `Request.IsAuthenticated` I get true.

The `CreateTicket` will create a cookie with the user info.

```
    private bool CreateCookie(string username, string type, DateTime cookieTime)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.Initialize();

        var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, username, DateTime.Now, cookieTime, true, type, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

        try
        {
            Response.Cookies.Remove(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
        }
        catch (Exception) { }

        var hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash);

        if (ticket.IsPersistent)
            cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        return true;
    }
```

The cookie is also correctly created, as I can see it in the browser.

My issue is after the redirect to `Default.aspx`. In this page I perform a validation to check if the user is authenticated, by doing `Request.IsAuthenticated`, which returns false and redirects me to the `Login.aspx` page.

The `Context.User` is getting cleaned, which is why `Request.IsAuthenticated` return false. I was hopping that someone could tell me why this happens and how to fix this.

**Other code that might be important:**

My OAuth configuration in the Startup:

```
    public static void Configure(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Login.aspx")
        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(appId: "...", appSecret: "...");
    }
```

My web config is:

```
<authentication mode="None"/>
```

**Note:**

Initially I was trying to integrate the OAuth using the `<authentication mode="Forms">`, but I was always getting redirected to the login page. I believe this happened because my web application didn't recognized the External Provider URL, so it redirected me to the `login.aspx` page. I tried to add it as an exception using the `location` tags in `web.config` but no success.